# X-Frame-Options not blocking iframe

Tags: apache, iframe, x-frame-options

I have set the X-Frame-Options header in Apache to DENY. The response header is correctly sent to the browser (see image). I just created a simple HTML file that loads an iframe which is loaded without any issue. I also checked Chrome devtools and the response header returns "x-frame-options: DENY". I was assuming that the header would block all iframes from being loaded?

[X-Frame-Options Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWjaH.png)

[Full Response Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b5el.png)

Comment: It's better to use SAMEORIGIN instead of DENY, otherwise, you will not be able to put your own site content to your own site's iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. `X-Frame-Options: DENY` prevent YOUR page from being loaded inside an `iframe`.

`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` - will block only loading from other domains.

It does nothing with iframes on the current page.

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a , ,

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: That explains! I was misinterpreting ClickJacking attacks as injecting a malicious iframe (by exploiting other vulnerabilities) onto the original webpage which could than be prevented by telling the browser to deny loading iframes. But that is not the case, thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Please do not send Access-Control-Allow-Origin to response if you are sending it. That could solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I do not send a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.